# setting mount options on an USB drive automounted by Gnome

Tags: gnome, usb-drive, automount

My USB drive is currently automounted correctly under Gnome (Ubuntu 18.04), but I want to set the "noatime" option at mount.

I know I can do this via the Gnome "disks" untility, but I prefer to document in code what I did to set up my system, so I'm looking for the command-line way to do this.

Comment: The following links may help you, [Auto mount, and change mount points on login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960156/auto-mount-and-change-mount-points-on-login/960173#960173) and [Mount NTFS partition in a USB drive with custom permissions and owner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072) -- Add the mount option `noatime` among the other mount options (in a comma separated list).

Comment: These will play nice with the user-mount that Gnome does on my behalf?

Comment: What I suggest is to mount the drive either via a line in the file `/etc/fstab` or a command line with `mount`. The same options apply in both cases, and if already mounted, the system should not mount it again. What file systems are there on the drive? How is it mounted now? You can find out by looking into the file `/etc/mtab` (when it is mounted).

Comment: It's mounted as

/dev/sdb1 /media/emile/ShittySSD ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,block_validity,discard,delalloc,nojournal_checksum,barrier,user_xattr,acl 0 0

but wouldn't adding it to fstab preclude a user mount?

Comment: If you add a partition to fstab, it will normally be mounted automatically at boot, and there will be problems, if the partition in not available (if the USB drive is not plugged in). But you can use the mount option `noauto`, it will *not* be automatically mounted, yet the mount options are there and the operating system is ready to mount it, whenever you want (and have the USB drive connected). It is enough to specify the device or mount point for example `sudo mount /dev/sdb1` or `sudo mount /mnt/sssd` (if you have made and specified the mount point `/mnt/sssd`).

Answer (score 3):

First run `df` to see what device your external drive is, for example, for me the appropriate line looks like this:

```
/dev/sdc1              4883769340 2392246688 2491522652  49% /media/drew/LACIE-5GB
```

`/media/drew/LACIE-5GB` is where the disk got mounted and the appropriate device is `/dev/sdc1` - this can change depending on how many external drives you have and in what order they were connected.

```
blkid /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="LACIE-5GB" UUID="703C31971BEBAA7E" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos" PARTLABEL="LACIE-5GB" PARTUUID="6afdadd9-39ce-4875-b747-82cae734ae02"
```

The UUID is `703C31971BEBAA7E`

So one can put a line like this into /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=703C31971BEBAA7E   /media/drew/LACIE-5GB   ntfs    defaults,noauto,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0000,fmask=0111      0       0
```

Note that `noauto` is important - if the drive is not connected on startup and that option is not present, the boot halts and needs to be manually restarted. `uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0000,fmask=0111` are just options for NTFS not to make every file executable (which prompts Nautilus to ask if a file is to be displayed or run when I try to read a txt file, for example). `noatime` is the option originally requested.

Comment: isn't that a typo? Don't you mean "fstab" instead of "fstav"?

Comment: yes, it is, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the perfect solution, but I created an `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf` file with just:

```
[defaults]
defaults=noatime
```

Running `cat /proc/mounts` shows my removable drives mounted with `noatime`. This is great for me since I'm convinced defaulting to `noatime` is a step forward.

The `udisks` man page is useful as well as https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Udisks#Udisks (the archlinux wiki is consistently helpful).