# Where are the options for automounted USB drives or how is automounting done in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, mount, automount, udisks

In Ubuntu 20.04 (as in previous versions), external USB drives are automatically mounted when they are plugged in, and an icon for each partition appears in the Dock.

How is that working? Which services take care of that, and where do they get the details for their configuration?

In particular, I would like to change mount options for NTFS and HFS+ partitions.

There are [several](https://askubuntu.com/q/1038143) [similar](https://askubuntu.com/q/1138449) questions, but they seem more focused on specific drives, and the answers send to `/etc/fstab`, or using the Disks utility (gnome-disk-utility) to edit options which will only apply to one specific drive or partition.

The [AutomaticallyMountPartitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions) page mentions `udisks`, but only shows how to use it interactively and doesn't describe how it interacts with the other parts.

I can also find `udev` rules with scripts to automount partitions, but the system already does that.

Comment: have you looked at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsbDriveDoSomethingHowto ?

Comment: @Jad: unfortunately, nothing new in these pages. And, yes, I had already installed dconf-editor to look for settings there, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide specific mount options for automatically mounted partitions in a file `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf`. For example, one could set options for a specific drive as:

```
[/dev/disk/by-uuid/18afd8f0-0d86-4d96-8de0-5f92d2ee9800]
defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,noexec
```

See `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf.example` for details and examples on how changes can be changed, globally or for specific drives and/or file systems.

Comment: Are you sure you were looking on ubuntu 20.04? Can't find `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf.example` ^^

Comment: No, I only have Ubuntu 21.10. I will leave the answer up for future users.