# Mount from fstab always mounts as root

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, nfs

I've read all the related questions but I can't make it work. On my ubuntu 16.04 server I want to mount an external vfat disk to share via nfs.

I have made a folder (/media/passport) which finally belongs to `nobody:nogroup` and anyone has full privileges but when rebooting the `/media/passport` folder belongs to `root:root`.

My client can see the nfs (as nfs://192.168.0.2/passport) but cannot proceed further (cannot read the folders and files in it).

The fstab file has the line:
`UUID=THEUUID /media/passport rw,users,utf8 0 0`

Anything I have read in stackoverflow promises to solve my issue but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Changing the mounted disc to ext4 (instead of vfat) gives me the same results; I can see the `nfs://server/passport` but I cannot browse further. I have tried all possible options both in `/etc/fstab` and in `/etc/exports`.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960156/auto-mount-and-change-mount-points-on-login/960173#960173) and links from it will help you.

Comment: Same problem but even without fstab, whatever I add to mount command as parameter, it always changes ownership of the folder to root:root and forbids any changes. I have no idea what is the cause; the filesystem of the usb disk is FAT32.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand - you want to share your directory to somebody over network. If so - try to look in the direction "/etc/exports" for example [here](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/understanding-the-etc-exports-file/)

Comment: I can't figure out if it is the export that doesn't work or the mounting. I can see the nfs and when trying to connect I get the `nfs://server/passport` part but I cannot browse further.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the client mounts the share via NFSv4. Try mounting it via NFSv3. Option is vers=3.

Comment: The "client" is the Minix tvbox and it doesn't give any nfs mounting options.

Comment: Can you try disabling NFSv4 on the server side then? Something like RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids --no-nfs-version 4" in /etc/default/nfs-kernel-server might do. Don't forget to reboot.