# Is there a way to copy files between drives via Ubuntu GUI?

Tags: gui, drive, copy-and-paste

First I can't open my other drives. There's an error `unknown filesystem type 'exfat'`. I solved this by installing `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils`. Now I can open my other drives.

But now I want to copy files from my Ubuntu drive partition to the other drives via the ubuntu GUI, but I can't copy it. The `paste` command is disabled.

I know there's a command line way to do this, but I want to do this via GUI. It's faster to do this via GUI and I don't have to memorize commands.

Is there a program that I can install to make this possible?

Comment: This should just work. Have you rebooted? How are the exFAT drives connected? (Usb or sata) Can you copy and paste to a usb thumb drive? (Formatted exFAT)

Comment: Maybe your partition with exFAT is mounted read-only (so that you are not allowed to write to it). In that case you can unmount it and mount it read-write. Maybe the owner of the exFAT is root and not your own userID. In that case you can unmount it and mount it with your own userID. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960156/auto-mount-and-change-mount-points-on-login/960173#960173) and links from it may help.

Comment: Might be worth copying a file using the command line to test that works. “cp path/to/source path/to/destination “. If sudokus is right you get errors that should confirm it. Good shout sudokus!

Comment: @PonJar, the exFAT drives is HDD, year via sata.

Comment: @sudodus, should I reformat my partition to another filesystem? Like fat32?

Comment: It makes no difference what medium it is USB pendrive, SD card, SDD, HDD ...

Comment: I don't think you need to re-format, I *think* it works with the same mount options for exFAT as with FAT32 and NTFS. But if you wish, you can create a new file system. In that case I would suggest the linux file system `ext4`, where you have full control of ownership and permissions on the directory and file level like in the internal drive.

Comment: @sudodus, thanks that solves my problem. Can you make that as an answer so I can award you the best answer.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you solve your problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your partition with exFAT is mounted read-only (so that you are not allowed to write to it). In that case you can unmount it and mount it read-write. Maybe the owner of the exFAT is root and not your own userID. In that case you can unmount it and mount it with your own userID. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960156/auto-mount-and-change-mount-points-on-login/960173#960173) and links from it may help.

I don't think you need to re-format, I think it works with the same mount options for exFAT as with FAT32 and NTFS. But if you wish, you can create a new file system. In that case I would suggest the linux file system **`ext4`**, where you have full control of ownership and permissions on the directory and file level like in the internal drive.